# Не получается добавить AdMod в Android app

Tags: android, admob

Ошибки:

```
W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

Код вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myapp">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Код класса:

```
private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Все делал по видео StartAndroid используя Firebase

```
<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">"Идентификатор рекламного блока"</string>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Что я делаю не так? От AdMod пришло письмо с поздравлениями с первыми показами, но рекламы нет(

Answer (score 2):

В `onCreate()` есть?

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "Идентификатор рекламного блока");
```

---

в `Manifest` добавлен?

```
<activity
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

---

`com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.1` и `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` присутствуют в `Gradle` на уровне приложения?

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    ...
    com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.1//?
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'//?
```

---

Добавлен ли `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'`  в `Gradle` на уровне проекта?

```
dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'//?
}
```

---

[тут](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-how-to-integrate-google-admob-in-your-app/) рассказано как проверить рекламу в тестовом режиме

Comment: в MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "Идентификатор рекламного блока"); "Идентификатор рекламного блока" должен быть такой же как banner_ad_unit_id, или тот что пишел на пошту с ~ вместо / и другим значением после него?

Comment: @АндрейШпилевой с почты

Comment: @АндрейШпилевой решилась проблема?

Comment: Оказалось проблема в моей невнимательности, но Ваши ответы натолкнули меня на решение!))) Спасибо!

Comment: @АндрейШпилевой рад был помочь:)